# Titanium Classic or Alloy for Dynamic Forms

Tags: forms, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I want to develop an application which is getting form data via JSON from an external database. I need to create the form fields and its properties according this dynamic data.

It seemed to me that I need to use the classical way in Titanium instead of alloy because I think I can not add any rows dynamically on the xml (view) side in Alloy. Am I correct or is it also possible to do it in Alloy? If yes can you please tell me how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done.  Using this widget https://github.com/albinotonnina/it.numidia.gridWidget I was able to figure out how to create dynamic content in Alloy.  Similar to the method used in this widget, I have a controller for each item I want to support.  I created a textfield, textarea, label among others.  It allows me to still use the Alloy styling and dynamically add the elements to my views.

Here is an example of my textfield controller:

XML

```
<Alloy>
    <TextField id="textfield"/>
</Alloy>
```

js

```
function applyProperties(_props){
    var apply = {};

    _.extend(apply, _.pick(_props, 'left', 'value', 'textAlign', 'font', 'color', 'shadowOff'));
    // alert(apply);
    $.textfield.applyProperties(apply);
}

exports.getContent = function(){
    return $.textfield.value;
};
exports.setContent = function(val){
    $.textfield.value = val;
};


if(arguments[0]){
    applyProperties(arguments[0]);
}

exports.applyProperties = applyProperties;
```

The style is completely empty since I'm using the app.tss to style this element.

Comment: Hey Martin - this is a really cool idea.  Do you still recommend this approach?  Is there a public repository of input widgets?

Comment: This was the closest I found that consolidated them http://alloylove.com/.  Otherwise I tend to find them searching around the web or github repositories.